# Can't retrieve data using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm currently studing NHibernate and I encountered a problem with my first application

My model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="ConsoleApplication1" 
                   namespace="ConsoleApplication1">

  <class name="Customer">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

NHibernate configuration and retrieving the data

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionConfiguration = new Configuration();
            connectionConfiguration.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {

            x.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=NHibernateTutorial;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            //Defining SQL Server as our DB
            x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
            //Defining the SQL Server version as 2012
            x.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
        });

        //Defifnig the local assembly as the assembly were the mapping file can be found
        connectionConfiguration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //Start a connection to the DB
        var sessionFactory = connectionConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //Begin a transaction
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var customers = session.CreateCriteria<Customer>().List<Customer>();
                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
                }
                //Flush the data and end the transaction 
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

No exception was thrown and a connection to the DB has been made. However I'm not able to retrieve any data from the Customer table(customers is empty). I'm guessing the problem is with the mapping but I can't tell for sure... Any suggestions?

Comment: If there is data in Customer table, then this should works. If the table is empty, then customers also is empty. I cannot see any insert, so I'm not sure if there is data or not. Why don't you try insert then select to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, all your settings are correct, just one is missing. Your mapping file must be available for NHibernate and that means this:

- Mapping file must be named `xxx.hbm.xml`, e.g. **`Customer.hbm.xml`** *(that's default convention which could be changed, but... use `.hbm.xml`)*
- Mapping file ***(each)*** must be marked as Embedded Resource. So select that file in solution explorer, click properties (ala F4) and set the **`Build Action: Embedded Resource`**

Now your code will start to deliver data.